# export multiple WhatsApp conversations to .txt or .csv format

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, export

I need to export a lot of different conversations, they are not very old, maximum 1200 messages. However, the WhatsApp export tool only allows me to do it one by one, is there any way to do it faster?

regards

Answer (score 0):

The manual way of doing that is

```
> To email your chat history, follow these steps:
> 1. Open the chat you want to send by email.
> 2. Touch More options.
> 3. Touch More.
> 4. Tap Export chat.
> 5. Choose NO FILES or INCLUDE FILES.
> 6. Select the onedrive application and load. The email will be sent as a text. When the history is sent with attachments, only the most
> recent 10,000 messages are sent. Without files, you can send up to
> 40,000 most recent messages. These restrictions are due to the maximum
> size of the email.
```